# Android ActivityGroup Back Button

Tags: android, back, activitygroup

I have a small issue.  I have looked all over the internet but I cannot find a solution to my problem.  The problem I have is:

I have a TabHost that has 3 tabs.  The first tab opens Activity A.  In Activity A, I can press in a listview and it will change the `setContent()` to Activity B.  When I press the back button in Activity B, the `onBackPressed()` function of Activity A gets called.

How can I close Activity B and go back to Activity A `onBackPressed()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i did it

```
private void onBackPressed(){
    RootActivity parentActivity;
    parentActivity = (RootActivity) this.getParent();
    parentActivity.switchToSecondActivity();
} // here RootActivity is the tabhost
```

in RootActivity

```
public void switchToSecondActivity(){
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(SECOND); 
} //SECOND is an integer pointing location of the second activity. it starts from 0
```